# Wordpress hyperlink using REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Does anyone know how to add hyperlinks in Wordpress articles using the WP REST API ?

I can't find any tutorial/documentation about this, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way to do it easily:

simply add hyperlinks through the WP article writer interface then click on "Edit in HTML" then you can copy paste the html code of any given paragraph into your WP Rest API content.